# laravel - json_encodeing the returned value of trans function sent error when using single quote

Tags: php, json, laravel, lang

I have used this code inside lang folder inside the some_file.php

```
return [
    'some-text' => 'i\'d like to fix it! it doesn\'t work even if I change the single quotes to double one.',
];
```

Note that the returned value is correct but when I json_encode the value and print it inside an input hidden tag with `{!! json_encode('some_file.some_text') !!}` it sends me an error in firebug (I don't remember the code exactly and I have no access the code right now) but it had intermittent json in its error.

Answer (score 1):

Try inside double quotes

```
return [
'some-text' => "i\'d like to fix it! it doesn\'t work even if I change 
 the single quotes to double one.",
  ];
```

Comment: As I said I have tested this one either. No result :(